# Lorentz generators trace

Tags: quantum-field-theory, operators, representation-theory, trace

I am reading Peskin's and Schroeder's book "An introduction to Quantum Field Theory". At some point in Chapter 3.1, they write down a particular representation for the Lorentz generator of a vector field,
$$(\mathcal{J}^{\mu\nu})_{\alpha\beta}=i(
\delta^{\mu}_{\alpha}\delta^{\nu}_{\beta}-
\delta^{\mu}_{\beta}\delta^{\nu}_{\alpha})\tag{3.18}$$
and much later on, in Chapter 16.6, they state that the trace of two such generators should obey
$$\text{tr}[\mathcal{J}^{\rho\sigma}\mathcal{J}^{\alpha\beta}]=
(g^{\rho\alpha}g^{\sigma\beta}-g^{\rho\beta}g^{\sigma\alpha}) C(j)\tag{16.127}$$
with $C(j)=0,1,2$ for scalars, Dirac spinors and Vector fields respectiveley. Let us assume that I wish to check the validity of this statement for the case of vector fields.

**My attempt is the following:** I treat each generator as a matrix, and hence the product of two such spinors is given by $\mathcal{J}^{\rho\sigma}\mathcal{J}^{\alpha\beta}=(\mathcal{J}^{\rho\sigma})_{\gamma\delta}(\mathcal{J}^{\alpha\beta})_{\delta\epsilon}$ with sum over the index $\delta$ implied. Then,
$$\text{tr}[\mathcal{J}^{\rho\sigma}\mathcal{J}^{\alpha\beta}]=
\text{tr}[(\mathcal{J}^{\rho\sigma})_{\gamma\delta}(\mathcal{J}^{\alpha\beta})_{\delta\epsilon}]=
(\mathcal{J}^{\rho\sigma})_{\gamma\delta}(\mathcal{J}^{\alpha\beta})_{\delta\gamma}$$

By plugging in the expression for the Lorentz generator [Eq. (3.18)], one obtains the correct result. I still have some questions though.

**My questions are the following:**

1. Is treating each $\mathcal{J}^{\mu\nu}$ as a matrix with matrix elements $(\mathcal{J}^{\mu\nu})_{\alpha\beta}$, with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being the labels for the rows and columns, correct? This implies that the "matrix" multiplication is given by the summation of the repeated indices (in our case $\delta$).
2. Somewhere in my calculations I have made the assumption that $\delta_{\epsilon\eta}g^{\rho\epsilon}g^{\beta\eta}=g^{\rho\beta}$. Is this correct? My calculations say that it is, at least for the Minkowski metric. Is it true for other metrics as well?
3. I know I am allowed to raise and lower my Lorentz indices $\mu,\ \nu$ on $(\mathcal{J}^{\mu\nu})_{\alpha\beta}$ with the Minkowski metric. Am I allowed to do that for the spin indices as well, i.e. $(\mathcal{J}^{\mu\nu})_{\alpha\beta}=
   g_{\alpha\gamma}
   (\mathcal{J}^{\mu\nu})^{\gamma}_{\beta}$? And if so, why is that?

Comment: Why is this question closed? This is no homework question, I am just trying to understand if my derivation makes sense

Comment: It might not be a homework question, but it is clearly a check-my-work question, which is off-topic, too. Your question should be useful for a wider audience.

Comment: Okay, I just wanted to find out whether or not treating each generator as a matrix should do the work. I will rephrase then

Comment: 1: yes, but it pays to sum over indices with $g_{\epsilon\eta}g^{\rho\epsilon}g^{\beta\eta}= \delta^\rho_\eta g^{\beta \eta}=g^{\rho\beta}$, which takes care of the signs in the Minkowski metric.

Comment: Sorry, @CosmasZachos, I am not sure I entirely understand your answer. What do you mean sum over indices? And why do you have a metric instead of my Kronecker $\delta$ in your expression?

Comment: [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representation_theory_of_the_Lorentz_group#Explicit_formulas).

Comment: Indices are raised and lower by metrics, Minkowski or not. (3.18) mixes the μs with the  αs, so the same matrics apply to both. Matrix multiplication converts a contravariant vector to a different contravariant vector, so a matrix has a covariant and a contra variant index.

Comment: Okay, thank you so much @CosmasZachos